# Operational Amplifier and Strain Gauge

Tags: operational-amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier, strain-gage

My laboratory involves using a strain gauge and an instrumentation
amplifier to amplify the signal from the strain gauge. The op amp schematic is shown below:
[image]

Any assistance with the following questions would be greatly appreciated:

a) What is the gain of the op amp?

b) Does the scale become more or less accurate after the op amp is introduced?

c) Name three ways to help reduce the noise measured at the output?

d) In the context of the strain gauge, why is noise cancellation important?

Comment: is this a homework?

Comment: It is for a lab report

Comment: R3 is usually the same value as R2 in your schematic for a standard instrumentation amplifier..

Comment: There are a couple of answers at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/452085/not-understanding-how-the-gain-works-in-the-1st-stage-of-an-instrumentation-ampl/452095#452095

Answer (score 0):

As this is clearly homework/lab report. I will just post a link that explains how to calculate the gain of the instrumentation amplifier: 
https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-8/the-instrumentation-amplifier/

Also, for d: The output of a strain gauge transducer is very small so you need to eliminate noise as much as possible so that it will not affect the signal